# Are generic mob farms efficient on populated MP servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to build a mob farm on a generic minecraft survival server with around 60 people average online.

If I light up all caves around the mob farm. Build it high up into the sky and get afking, would the efficiency be the same as when I would play SP on my computer? Or at least comparable?

Plan on building this one:

Comment: I've never seen a problem with it.

Comment: @Ben I never tried, And don't wanna waste my time building such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mumbo did this on the HermitCraft Server](https://youtu.be/ENRy2P3BTB4), using the same design (except bigger) with no issues.

My only suggestion is make sure that there is a way to "turn it off" when you're not needing it. The video also covers the redstone mechanisms to turn it on and off.

Comment: I know the turn of thingy. But will it also work with more players than 1-8 which are mostly on hermitcraft?

Comment: I don't see why not. The server may experience some lag, depending on how big you build it, but of the server is beefy enough, it shouldn't be a problem. The efficiency will still be the the same.

Answer (score 1):

On servers there is a mob spawn limit so when large parts of the map are loaded the mob spawn limit is distributed between them so your farm may not be efficient or it may even not produce any mobs at all.

Comment: I do will try to build it